# Cannot make this flexbox layout responsive enough

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, media-queries

I have little complicated layout made with flexbox, I have a problem with responsive, this is not working in responsive:

```css
section {
  max-width: 740px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
 .column {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
 section:nth-of-type(5) .column:first-of-type {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  flex-basis: 22px;
}
 section:nth-of-type(6) .column:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-shrink: 4;
  flex-basis: 66px;
}
/* OTHER STYLES */
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b04, #f80) fixed;
}
 .column {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>


<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
  
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
 
</section>
```

What I am trying to achieve is that columns get full width on mobile, right now it is not like that, to get an idea I add a picture of what I want to this layout to look like on mobile:

[image]

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

So I added a css breakpoint for the section tag as you can see at the end of css lines. So below 480px window width you will have full width of the elements.

```css
section {
  max-width: 740px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
 .column {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

/* OTHER STYLES */
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b04, #f80) fixed;
}
 .column {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
/* MEDIA QUERY */
@media(min-width: 481px) {
    section:nth-of-type(5) .column:first-of-type {
        flex-grow: 2;
        flex-shrink: 2;
        flex-basis: 22px;
    }

    section:nth-of-type(6) .column:nth-of-type(2) {
        flex-grow: 4;
        flex-shrink: 4;
        flex-basis: 66px;
    }
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
    section {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>


<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
  
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<section>
      <div class="column">aa</div> 
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="column">1</div>
      <div class="column">2</div>
      <div class="column">3</div>

    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="column">aa</div> 
    </section>


    <section>
      <div class="column">1</div>
      <div class="column">2</div>
      <div class="column">3</div>
      <div class="column">4</div>

    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="column">aa</div> 
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="column">1</div>
      <div class="column">2</div>
      <div class="column">3</div>

    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
     max-width: 740px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap ;
}
 .column {
     margin: 10px;
     flex-grow: 1;
     flex-shrink: 1;
}
 section:nth-of-type(5) .column:first-of-type {
     flex-grow: 2;
     flex-shrink: 2;
     flex-basis: 22px;
}
 section:nth-of-type(6) .column:nth-of-type(2) {
     flex-grow: 4;
     flex-shrink: 4;
     flex-basis: 66px;
}
/* OTHER STYLES */
 html, body {
     height: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     padding: 10px;
     background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b04, #f80) fixed;
}
 .column {
     padding: 10px 0;
     background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
     color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

@media(max-width: 576px) {
  .column {
    flex-basis: 576px ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in two ways,
1) By giving `flex-direction: column;` to section 
2) By giving `flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap` and its children (i.e column) `flex: 1 1 100%;`
Example

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   section {
     flex-direction: column;
     -webkit-flex-direction: column;
   }
}
```

Or

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
   section {
     flex-direction: row;
     -webkit-flex-direction: row;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .column {
     flex: 1 1 100%;
     -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a media query where you change `display` to `block` for all sections (set the breakpoint as needed, here it's 720px to immediately show the mobile version, but of course you can adjust that for example to 480px).

```
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  section {
     display: block;
  }
}
```

This will deactivate all the flex parameters and set `width` to `auto` (= full width)

```css
section {
  max-width: 740px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
 .column {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
 section:nth-of-type(5) .column:first-of-type {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 2;
  flex-basis: 22px;
}
 section:nth-of-type(6) .column:nth-of-type(2) {
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-shrink: 4;
  flex-basis: 66px;
}
/* OTHER STYLES */
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b04, #f80) fixed;
}
 .column {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  section {
  display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>


<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
  
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">aa</div> 
</section>

<section>
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
 
</section>
```